# Mean and Variance of a Logarithmic Distribution

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

I'm studying probability theory and ran into a question regarding the mean and variance of distributions that I'm having difficulty with. To be a bit more specific,

> **Question:** (From *Introduction to Probability (2e) - Blitzstein & Hwang*)
>
> Let $X$ have PMF
>
> $$P(X=k)\ =\ c\frac{p^k}{k}\ (k = 1,\ 2,\ ...)$$
>
> where $p$ is a parameter with $0 \lt p \lt 1$ and $c$ is a normalizing constant. We have $c=\frac{-1}{\log(1-p)}$, as seen from the Taylor series
>
> $$-\log(1-p) = p\ +\ \frac{p^2}{2}\ +\ \frac{p^3}{3}\ +\ ...$$
>
> This distribution is called the *Logarithmic* distribution. Find the mean and variance of $X$.

I was able to find $E(X)$ quite easily, but am having trouble finding $E(X^2)$.

\begin{align}
E(X)& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \times c\frac{p^k}{k} \\
& = c\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \times \frac{p^k}{k} \\
& = c\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k \\
& = \frac{-1}{(1-p)\log(1-p)} \\
\end{align}

When finding $E(X)$, I'm using the same approach, but with $k^2$ instead of $k$. This leaves me with $\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^k$. How do I deal with this kind of series?

**EDIT**

Apparently, my mean calculation is also wrong. From this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution) it states that the expected value for a Logarithmic distribution is

$$E(X) = \frac{-p}{(1-p)\log(1-p)}$$

I don't understand how the $p$ appeared in the numerator. Would anybody be kind enough to give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Think of it as the first derivative of a geometric sum of $p^k$

Comment: Oh! That actually makes sense I hadn't thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the confusion, I've found the answer thanks to a hint from Fede Poncio in the comment on the original question. Also, the second part of my question in the **Edit** section originates from my initial lack of understanding of geometric series.

\begin{align}
E(X) & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \times c \frac{p^k}{k}\\
& = c\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k \\
& = c\sum_{k=1}^\infty p \times p^{k-1} \\
& = -\frac{p}{\log(1-p)}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{k-1} \\
& = -\frac{p}{\log(1-p)}\frac{1}{1-p} \\
& = -\frac{p}{(1-p)\log(1-p)}
\end{align}

I forgot that geometric series should start from the case of $x^0$, not $x^1$. And since I changed the base of the summation from $k=0$ to $k=1$, the appropriate changes to the ratio $p$ were also made.

\begin{align}
E(X^2) & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2 \times c\frac{p^k}{k} \\
& = cp\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1} \\
& = -\frac{1}{\log(1-p)} \times \frac{p}{(1-p)^2} \\
& = -\frac{p}{(1-p)^2\log(1-p)} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Var(X) & = E(X^2)\ -\ (E(X))^2 \\
& = -\frac{p}{(1-p)^2\log(1-p)}\ -\ \frac{p^2}{(1-p)^2(\log(1-p))^2} \\
& = -\frac{p\log(1-p)\ +\ p^2}{(1-p)^2(\log(1-p))^2} \\
& = -\frac{p^2\ +\ p\log(1-p)}{(1-p)^2(\log(1-p))^2}
\end{align}

You can verify that these are correct from the [Wikipedia page for the Logarithmic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution).

For anybody who's also wondering how I initially did about the series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1}$$

as Fede Poncio pointed out, it helps if you observe that this is the first derivative of the series:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^k = \frac{1}{1-p} \\
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1} = \frac{1}{(1-p)^2} \\
\end{align}